# Ordinary Least Squares in statsmodels: Our model needs an intercept

Tags: python, regression

I'm starting to learn about linear regression and got stumped right at the beginning. I think my problem is not conceptually but about the implementation. I don't understand why, as per the [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html), I need to include an extra column with the intercept of value 1 when trying to fit a regression line.

```
#Artificial data:
nsample = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
X = np.column_stack((x, x**2))
beta = np.array([1, 0.1, 10])
e = np.random.normal(size=nsample)

#Our model needs an intercept so we add a column of 1s:
X = sm.add_constant(X)
y = np.dot(X, beta) + e

#Fit and summary:
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())
```

Isn't the intercept determined by the data? Why do I need to specify what it is? Or is this more like an parameter, where no intercept or intercept=0 means the regression line is forced through the origin and otherwise it is calculated? Why would I specify an intercept other than 0 or 1, like 100000?

Comment: A column of ones is just the way to get the intercept parameter with the design matrix. The non-formula interface takes the design matrix as defined by the user and does not change it. So, if you want an intercept, then we need to add it ourselves as users. Alternatively, you can use the formula interface which adds an intercept by default.

Comment: Consider using linear regression to fit a quadratic equation that is written as "y = (a * x^0) + (b * x^1) + (c * x^2)" . Since x^0 = 1, you would fit a column of ones to find the  parameter "a".